# R: Mediation Analysis, output shows an ACME of 0

Tags: r, interpretation, mediation

My first mediation analysis and something is wrong...The relationship between the independent variable (“Bedingung”) and the dependent variable (“Liking”) is significant as is the relationship between the IV and the mediator (“Similarity”). When including the mediator into the regression the relationship between the IV and DV decreases significantly (partial mediation?). But for some reason when testing whether the partial mediation is significant, the ouput shows an ACME equal to zero (see screenshot).

Can someone help?

[image]

Here is my whole code :)

```
#Mediatoranalyse
##step 1, Effekt von UV auf AV, hier signifikant
med.fit <- lm(Liking ~ Bedingung, data = d)
summary(med.fit)

##step 2 gucken, ob signifikanter Effekt der UV auf Mediator  
out.fit <- lm(Similarity ~ Bedingung, data = d)
summary(out.fit)
###ist signifikant

##step 3, gucken, ob der Zusammenhang zwischen UV und AV trotz Mediator noch besteht
SimiMediation <- lm(Liking ~ Bedingung + Similarity, d)
summary(SimiMediation)
###partielle Mediation, der Effekt verschwindet nicht, wird aber kleiner

##step 4 jetzt testen, ob signifikant

med.out <- mediate(out.fit, med.fit, sims = 3000, boot = TRUE, 
                   treat ="Bedingung", mediator = "Similarity")
summary(med.out)
```

Comment: the ouput is the picture above showing an ACME = 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Your call to mediate is wrong. Label the arguments to prevent confusion. Otherwise the first object is assigned as the model for the mediator, the second object is assigned as the model for the outcome. You've reversed these.  See `?mediate` for details.